# onSearchRequested() not working after renaming Package

Tags: android

I've renamed my android app package via Android Tools -> Rename Application Package, but after renaming it I'm unable to see the search box when invoking onSearchRequested() which works fine if i change the package name back to its original value, is there something else that's needed to be changed?

**[edit]**

Following is the class that is responsible for invoking onSearchRequested():

```
public class SearchAction implements Action {

    Activity _activity;

    public SearchAction(Activity activity){

        _activity = activity;

    }

    public int getDrawable() {

        return R.drawable.ic_action_menu;

    }

    public void performAction(View view) {

        _activity.onSearchRequested();

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show some code considering the onSearchRequested()?

Comment: @LeonLucardie I've included the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you use a fully qualified naming scheme in your AndroidManifest.xml. You have to change the package name there as well.

For these elements:

```
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
       android:value="your.package.YourSearchActivity" />
```

Comment: Bulls Eye, Bang On... Thanks a lot for your help! :)